# Как сразу прописать обращение ко всей папке css дочерней темы?

Tags: css, wordpress

Нашла здесь отлично работающую штуку:

```
function my_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap.min.css', array("storefront-style") );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles' );
```

С помощью этой функции можно править стилевой файл `bootstrap.min.css` в дочерней теме.

Хороший совет. Отлично работает с каждым отдельным файлом из папки css, скопированной в дочернюю тему. Но там этих файлов ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО. Есть функция, которая сразу на всю папку перенаправит?

**Здесь к default.css обращается, а к bootstrap.css - нет.**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );
function my_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'default', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/default.css', array( 'elitepress-style' ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles' );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 12 );
function boot_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap.css', array( 'elitepress-style' ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'boot_styles' );
```

Comment: Не надо плодить вопросы. Я вам уже ответил в комментарии к другому вопросу, который вы удалили, кажется.

Comment: Нет такой функции. Более того, это лишнее и неправильное действие. В дочернюю тему надо переносить только то, что будет изменено. Иначе следующий после вас девелопер проклянет вас при обновлении основной темы, сравнивая все эти файлы.

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда почему в одном случае эта функция работает, а такая же с другими параметрами не перенаправляет на то, "что будет изменено"? И от менторского тона воздержитесь, если не трудно.

Comment: Покажите пример, в котором два вызова: один работает, другой не работает. Под вопросом есть кнопка "править".

Comment: В приведенном коде ошибок нет. Либо сам файл `bootstrap.css` отсутствует, либо ещё какие-то иные проблемы в коде. Непонятно, зачем тут два вызова одной и той же функции `chld_thm_cfg_parent_css` с приоритетами 10 и 12. А сама она не приведена.

Comment: Тема дочерняя. Созавалась плагином Чайлд Тем. Это от него осталось. Плагин прописался в functions.php так: if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'elitepress-bootstrap' ) );
    }
endif;

Comment: Непонятно, что еще сделал этот плагин. Попробуйте удалить эту дочернюю тему и создать новую вручную. Это очень просто: https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html